# When does the LORD send an angel to replace Him to lead the Israelites?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 33

> <sup>**1**</sup> The LORD said to Moses, “Depart; go up from here, you and the people whom you have brought up out of the land of Egypt, to the land of which I swore to Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, saying, ‘To your offspring I will give it.’ <sup>**2**</sup> I will send an angel before you, and I will drive out the Canaanites, the Amorites, the Hittites, the Perizzites, the Hivites, and the Jebusites. <sup>**3**</sup> Go up to a land flowing with milk and honey; but I will not go up among you, lest I consume you on the way, for you are a stiff-necked people.”

When does the LORD send an angel to replace Him to lead the Israelites?

Comment: The Lord isn’t literally there leading, He has His logos and spirit to do His expression and provision. The angels are another way he does this.

Comment: @William Hi William, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exodus 33:

> 2 I will send an **angel** before you and drive out the Canaanites, Amorites, Hittites, Perizzites, Hivites and Jebusites. 3 Go up to the land flowing with milk and honey. But **I will not** go with you, because you are a stiff-necked people and I might destroy you on the way.”

When does the LORD send an angel to **replace** Him to lead the Israelites?

He didn't, at least not a complete replacement.

> 12 Moses said to the Lord, “You have been telling me, ‘Lead these people,’ but you have not let me know **whom you will send** with **me**. You have said, ‘I know you by name and you have found favor with me.’ 13If you are pleased with me, teach me your ways so I may know you and continue to find favor with you. Remember that this nation is your people.”
>
> 14 The Lord replied, “**My Presence** will go with **you** [plural], and I will give you rest.”
>
> 15 Then Moses said to him, “If your Presence does not go with us, do not send us up from here. 16How will anyone know that you are pleased with me and with your people unless you go with us? What else will distinguish me and your people from all the other people on the face of the earth?”
>
> 17 And the Lord said to Moses, “I **will do** the very thing you have asked, because I am pleased with you and I know you by name.”
>
> 18 Then Moses said, “Now show me your **glory**.”

The book of Exodus ends with 40:

> 34 Then the cloud covered the Tent of Meeting, and the **glory of the LORD** filled the tabernacle. 35Moses was unable to enter the Tent of Meeting because the **cloud** had settled on it, and the glory of the LORD filled the tabernacle.
>
> 36 Whenever the cloud was lifted from above the tabernacle, the Israelites would set out through all the stages of their journey. 37If the cloud was not lifted, they would not set out until the day it was taken up. 38 For the **cloud of the LORD** was over the tabernacle by day, and fire was in the cloud by night, in the sight of all the house of Israel through all their journeys.

The Presence of the LORD, the glory of the LORD, and the cloud of the LORD were with the Israelites through all their journeys in the wilderness.

Answer (score 0):

The reason God gives is:

> but I will not go up among you, lest I consume you on the way, for you are a stiff-necked people.”
> (Exodus 33:3, ESV)

Another reason is God often used angels to appear to people because we cannot look at the face of God.

> 17 And the LORD said to Moses, “This very thing that you have spoken I will do, for you have found favor in my sight, and I know you by name.” 18 Moses said, “Please show me your glory.” 19 And he said, “I will make all my goodness pass before you and will proclaim before you my name ‘The LORD.’ And I will be gracious to whom I will be gracious, and will show mercy on whom I will show mercy. 20 But,” he said, **“you cannot see my face, for man shall not see me and live.”** 21 And the LORD said, “Behold, there is a place by me where you shall stand on the rock, 22 and while my glory passes by I will put you in a cleft of the rock, and I will cover you with my hand until I have passed by. 23 Then I will take away my hand, and you shall see my back, but my face shall not be seen.”
> (Exodus 33:17–23, ESV)

There is also:

> And the people complained in the hearing of the LORD about their misfortunes, and when the LORD heard it, his anger was kindled, and **the fire of the LORD burned among them and consumed some outlying parts of the camp.** 2 Then the people cried out to Moses, and Moses prayed to the LORD, and the fire died down. 3 So the name of that place was called Taberah, because the fire of the LORD burned among them.
> (Num. 11:1–3)

and

> From Mount Hor they set out by the way to the Red Sea, to go around the land of Edom. And the people became impatient on the way. 5 And the people spoke against God and against Moses, “Why have you brought us up out of Egypt to die in the wilderness? For there is no food and no water, and we loathe this worthless food.” 6 Then **the LORD sent fiery serpents among the people, and they bit the people, so that many people of Israel died.** 7 And the people came to Moses and said, “We have sinned, for we have spoken against the LORD and against you. Pray to the LORD, that he take away the serpents from us.” So Moses prayed for the people. 8 And the LORD said to Moses, “Make a fiery serpent and set it on a pole, and everyone who is bitten, when he sees it, shall live.” 9 So Moses made a bronze serpent and set it on a pole. And if a serpent bit anyone, he would look at the bronze serpent and live.
> (Num. 21:4–9, ESV)